# What are relationship between cable properties and electrical properties?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, cables

I was prototyping esp32-cam (microcontroller aka MCU) on breadboard, I saw **brownout** error message on serial monitor everytime I initialize WiFi then it keeps restarting. After I google for 24 hours non-stop I learned it was power issue.

My schematic is just:

esp32-cam module (on breadboard with long cable jumper) <--> usb to ttl (with long jumper) <--> laptop (as power supply)

I realized even though it powered the MCU with powered through long cable jumper, It can just do basic things like write/read GPIO meanwhile when I started the WiFi, it keeps restarting that I mentioned above.

But when I try with shorter jumper cable and without breadboard, WiFi on MCU and Camera is working fine.
esp32-cam (without breadboard) <--> usb to ttl <--> laptop

I'm wondering why it was failed when I tried on breadboard. Is there because cable quality or breadboard quality?

So I think there's relationship between  Cable (Conductor) Properties and Electrical Properties (such as Current, Voltage, Resistance) like More Long cable more poor current or somewhat?

Comment: No such thing as “poor current”. Current is current. What you are after is voltage drop due to cable resistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module needs a lot of current when it is transmitting, and, it needs the current to be available quickly.

If you have too thin wires that are too long, they add too much resistance, and flowing current will cause too much voltage drop so the module has a brownout.

Also the wires add inductance, and longer wires add more inductance. Inductance causes current to be available slowly, so it is not quickly available, and fast current pulse will drop voltage and result into brownout again. There needs to be some local energy storage at the module to make current to be quickly available to the module.

Comment: i.e. a capacitor in parallel with the module, close to the module. These are called decoupling capacitors.

Comment: Yes I just realized I learned RL circuit at my Univ, Inductor is making propagation current slower and Inductor is just basically just a normal conductor cable except constructed with spiral.

Comment: @MuhammadIkhwanPerwira You don't need a spiral; even a straight wire has inductance; it's just not that much. But here, that straight wire inductance could be a problem. In things made to be inductors, they'll wind the wire into a coil to have more inductance with less copper and in a smaller area, but the coil is not a requirement for inductance.

Comment: if i make the power cable jumper (vcc and gnd) twisted pair, will it reduce inductance?